# $\tan x-\sin x\cos x$ simplified using trig identities

Tags: trigonometry

In my school textbook, it states that the answer is : $(\sin^2x)(\tan x)$'. However, I am unsure how they obtained this answer. I obtained this answer $\sin^2x+\tan x$.

`After looking closer I did this`:

Firstly I did $\frac {sinx}{cosx}-sinxcosx$. Then $\frac {sinx}{cosx}- \frac{sinxcos^2x}{cosx}$. Followed by $\frac {sinx}{cosx}- \frac{sinx(1-sin^2x)}{cosx}$. Which I then expanded as $\frac {sinx}{cosx}- \frac{sinx+sin^3x}{cosx}$. I then simplified to $ \frac{sin^3x}{cosx}$ by subtracting $sinx-sinx$. Then I treated it as $\frac {(sin^2x)(sinx)}{cosx}=\frac{sin^2x}{1} \cdot \frac{sinx}{cosx}$. This simplifies to $sin^2x \cdot tanx$ . Is this correct ?

Comment: You made an error somewhere.

Comment: Yes, your modified solution is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tan x - \sin x\cos x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\sin x\cos x= \frac{\sin x - \sin x \cos ^2x}{\cos  x} = \frac{\sin x (1 - \cos ^2x)}{\cos  x} = \tan x (1 - \cos ^2x) = \tan x \sin ^2 x$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align*}\tan x - \sin x \cos x & = \tan x - \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}\cos^2 x \\ & = \tan x(1-\cos^2 x) \\ & = \tan x \sin^2 x\end{align*}$$

I am not sure how you got $\sin^2 x + \tan x$.

Answer (score 1):

After obtaining an answer had you plugged in some value for x, say $45^{\circ}$ your answer would be $ \dfrac32 $ when book answer says $\dfrac12$ you would probably have checked your work to be incorrect.

Most probably you have continued with putting the addition sign even after getting the product $\sin^2x \tan x$ as answer.

If you shared your work steps, the error source would have been already pin-pointed. Not doing so did not help you so far.